# How to detect a "Recent Activities Tab button" press from a Service class (Android)?

Tags: android, dialog, android-input-method

This is my code:

```
public void displayQuickSettingsDialog() {
        if(quickSettingsDialog == null) {

            quickSettingsDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            quickSettingsDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            Window win = quickSettingsDialog.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = quickSettingsDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.token = mKptAdaptxtIME.mInputView.getWindowToken();
            lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
            lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
            lp.y = lp.y + 150;
            win.setAttributes(lp);
            win.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);



            quickSettingsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.quicksettings);
            quickSettingsDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            //listeners for dialog options
            quickSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.quick_sett_lang).setOnClickListener(this);
            quickSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.quick_sett_keyboard_type).setOnClickListener(this);
            quickSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.quick_sett_sugg_control).setOnClickListener(this);
            quickSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.quick_sett_settings).setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        quickSettingsDialog.show();
    }
```

It displays an alert dialog and everything is working fine, after displaying the dialog, when I pressed the recent activities Tab (4.0) and if I select some other activity  then the dialog still is not dismissed,  This method I am calling from a Input Method Service...In a service which call back will be called when I pressed the recent activities button? Help needed quickly...Thanks in advance androidians..

Comment: Title says "Home Key Press", but description "when I pressed the recent activities button". Would you please correct the one that's wrong.